# How to populate UIPickerView with .plist file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, uipickerview

I want to populate one.plist files from a number of .plist files as per the user selection . 
How to populate UIPickerView with a .plist file ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why not just load a .plist file into an array and then just fill in the UIPickerView with that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question well but here is what I guess. You may want to load data from a .plist file and then fill in the UIPickerView.

Here is a sample code for loading a .plist file:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"money.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
```